# Is the subgroup generated by two closed subgroups closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H_1, H_2$ be closed subgroups. Can we conclude that $\langle H_1, H_2 \rangle$ is closed?

My attempt is to show that $\overline{\langle H_1, H_2 \rangle} \subseteq \langle \overline{H}_1, \overline{H}_2 \rangle$. But I doubt that this result doesn't hold.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}, +$, consider the two subgroups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\langle \mathbb{Z}, \sqrt{2} \mathbb{Z} \rangle = \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{2}]$ which is proper and dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks!

Comment: @Kelenner, please post your upvoted comment as a "Hint" in an answer.  It was exactly what Victor needed to answer the question.  I will gladly upvote your answer, just ping me (@amWhy) when you do, and you can refer to a user (me) encouraging you to post your initial comment as an answer.   All you'd need to do is write: "HINT: $\langle$ insert your comment here $\rangle$".

Comment: @amWhy :Done, and many thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: In $\mathbb{R}$ as an additive subgroup, consider the two subgroups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$.